# Laravel eloquent relationship one to many

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I am working on three tables: product, delivery and stock. I want that when a product is delivered, its quantity in the stock table increases. So in the controller of the delivery table I wrote this code:

```
$produit = Produit::find($delivery['produit_id']); 
$quantite = $produit->stock->quantite;
$quantite += $delivery['quantite'];
$quantite->save();
```

but when I make a delivery, the quantity in the stock table does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply types in `PHP` is not by reference, so you have to assign the new value to the `Stock` object. This is assuming `quantite` is an integer on the `Stock` model, which is not totally clear in the code you provided, since you call `->save()` on quantite. Remember to save the `Stock` model instead of `quantite`.

```
$stock = $produit->stock;
$stock->quantite = $stock->quantite + $delivery['quantite']
$stock->save();
```